# Enviando Imagem Baixada para o servidor direto - HIGHCHARTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Estou usando uma API chamada highcharts, nela eu gero gráficos e consigo baixar imagens dele em png, eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer com que quando eu baixar essa imagem essa mesma imagem fique em uma pasta no servidor

Comment: Qual tecnologia você está usando no seu backend?

Comment: @d-aguilar Estou desenvolvendo em PHP

Comment: Eu fiz isso em C#. Uma ideia que pode te ajudar: O HighCharts gera um SVG no seu HTML. Você pode enviar o SVG para o servidor, logo em seguida converter esse SVG para PNG e salvar no seu servidor.

Comment: @d-aguilar não tenho muita ideia de como fazer isso, pesquiso sobre o que?

Answer (score 0):

utilize esse [lib - highcharts-phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-phantomjs)

Utilizando `[PhantomJS][1]` você consegue gerar seu gráfico, a partir de um arquivo `[json][1]`, utilizando simples linhas de comandos como:

`-infile -outfile`. Aonde infile é o arquivo json e out file é o nome do arquivo png e o caminho que ele será salvo no sevidor.